# Showing $\Delta h$ = $\vert f'(z) \vert^2 \Delta H$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplacian

Let $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ be defined on

$$\Omega \rightarrow D$$

where $\Omega,D$ are domains. Let $H(\zeta,\eta)$ be a real valued function defined on $D$ where $w=\zeta + i \eta$ Prove the composite function defined via

$$h(z)=H \circ f(z)$$

defined on $\Omega$ satisfies

$$\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial y^2}=\vert f'(z) \vert^2 \Delta H$$

where $\Delta H$ is the $2$ dimensional laplacian of $H$. First of all I don't understand why $H$ is real valued if it maps $(\zeta,\eta)$ to $\zeta + i \eta$. Secondly do I use the fact that $f'(z)=u_x+iv_x$? A little stuck on this one. I know I need to use the chain rule somewhere, am I right? Is the following the right approach

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial y^2} &= \frac{\partial^2 (H(f(z))}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 (H(f(z))}{\partial y^2}\\\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(H(f(z)))+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(H(f(z)))
\end{align}

then using chain rule? Can anybody help me on this please?!

Comment: That does not say that $H$ maps $(\zeta, \eta)$ to $\zeta + i\eta$.

Comment: what does it mean then by $w=\zeta+i\eta$ @Randall

Comment: It is telling you how it takes a complex number $w$ as input in terms of its real and imaginary parts as $w=\zeta + i \eta$, and the output $H(\zeta, \eta)$ is a real number.

Comment: So how do I show the equality @Randall

Comment: You have to add that $f(z)$ is analytic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic. Otherwise $f'(z)$ has no meaning. Let $w=f(z)$ and then
$$ \frac{\partial w}{\partial \bar z}=\frac{\partial \bar w}{\partial z}=0, \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial z\partial \bar z}= \frac{\partial^2 \bar w}{\partial z\partial \bar z}=0 $$  Noting
$$ \Delta f(z)=4\partial_z\partial_{\bar z}f(z)  $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta h&=&4\partial_z\partial_{\bar z}H(f((z))\\
&=&4\partial_z\partial_{\bar z}H(w)\\
&=&4\partial_z\bigg(\frac{\partial H(w)}{\partial w}\cdot\frac{\partial w}{\partial \bar z}+\frac{\partial H(w)}{\partial \bar w}\cdot\frac{\partial \bar w}{\partial \bar z}\bigg)\\
&=&4\partial_z\bigg(\frac{\partial H(w)}{\partial \bar w}\cdot\frac{\partial \bar w}{\partial \bar z}\bigg)\\
&=&4\bigg( \frac{\partial^2 H(w)}{\partial w\partial \bar w}\cdot\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\cdot\frac{\partial \bar w}{\partial \bar z}+\frac{\partial^2 H(w)}{\partial \bar w^2}\cdot\frac{\partial\bar w}{\partial z}\cdot\frac{\partial \bar w}{\partial \bar z}+\frac{\partial H(w)}{\partial \bar w}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 \bar w}{\partial z\partial \bar z}\bigg) \\
&=&4\frac{\partial^2 H(w)}{\partial w\partial \bar w}\cdot\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\cdot\frac{\partial \bar w}{\partial \bar z} \\
&=&\vert f'(z) \vert^2 \Delta H.
\end{eqnarray}